# Get exit code for Powershell Core script hosted in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, powershell-core

I am attempting to run a set of PowerShell scripts from within a .NET Core app using the framework outlined [here](https://medium.com/@thomaslagreca/powershell-commands-in-a-net-core-app-106438796648). The basic code is below:

```
using (var ps = Powershell.Create()) {
    ps.AddScript(script);
    var output = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
    await ps.InvokeAsync<PSObject, PSObject>(null, output);
}
```

My question is, how could I retrieve the exit code of the script?

Comment: AFAIK you can only do try catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible, although if it is I would love to know how it is done. As an alternative I am using Write-Output to indicate the exit code before calling exit in my script. Data written using Write-Output is available in the output collection.